# Unable to access node values when inside a soap envelope using groovy dombuilder

Tags: soap, groovy

Goal: I have a Soap Response message that I need to validate a specific element value. I want to use the Groovy DOMBuilder.

If I have a Soap Response such as this:

```
def xmlResponse =
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\n' +
            '   <soap:Body>\n' +
            '      <ns1:getResponse xmlns:ns1="http://my.company.com">\n' +
            '         <return>value1</return>\n' +
            '\t\t <return>value2</return>\n' +
            '      </ns1:getResponse>\n' +
            '   </soap:Body>\n' +
            '</soap:Envelope>'
```

and I use the following code:

```
def StringReader s = new StringReader(xmlResponse)
def xmldoc = groovy.xml.DOMBuilder.parse(s)
def elementName = xmldoc.documentElement
use (groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory) {
            println elementName.return.size()
            println elementName.return[0].text()
        }
```

elementName.return.size() is 0.  If I remove the soap envelope and soap body of my response I get the correct answer of 2.  I am not sure what I need to do such that I get the correct response with the right message.

Thank you in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy/cheap to use `XmlSlurper` instead:

```
def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xmlResponse ).Body.getResponse.'return'

assert slurped.size() == 2
assert slurped[0].text() == 'value1'
```

Comment: it certainly is easy enough.  thank you for your help!